# how to update user password?Devise + OpenID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, openid, omniauth

env:Rails + Devise + OmniAuth

while i login with Google OpenID,the site create a user automatically,and a random password.

but when i try to update user's password,that tells me:u need current password.

so i cannot update my password.(i could only login this site with Google OpenID.)

Is there any solutions?THX.

Comment: I think it would be convenient to update passwords without requiring the old one for users who came from OmniAuth, or else you can make user type password right after OmniAuth callback

Comment: @alony yes,but devise tells me that they need the old one.and when a user from OmniAuth,if he wanna update passwd,it still need the old one.....need help.

Comment: what about [this way](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) ?